# Java Hidden JTabbedPane

Tags: java, jtabbedpane, swingx

I want when I click on tab1 or tab2. Japel display will hide or show,I want the results shown in Figure 2.I use the command **jPanel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));**

Ex: If I have 10,I need setPreferredSize for 10 japanel with each tab.I want to ask a much easier way.

[image]

[image]

Events to click on my tab does not work properly.Please help me

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package main;

import java.awt.Dimension;

/**
 *
 * @author KhongTuyen
 */
public class demo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form demo
     */
    public demo() {
        initComponents();
        jPanel2.setVisible(false);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTabbedPane1.setTabPlacement(javax.swing.JTabbedPane.BOTTOM);
        jTabbedPane1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jTabbedPane1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jTabbedPane1.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                jTabbedPane1StateChanged(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel4.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(395, 0));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 395, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab1", jPanel4);

        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(395, 0));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 395, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab2", jPanel1);

        getContentPane().add(jTabbedPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 253, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel2, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTabbedPane1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        int count = 0;
        if (count % 2 != 0) {
            jPanel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 100));
            jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 100));
        } else {
            jPanel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
            jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
        }
        count++;
    }                                         

    private void jTabbedPane1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(demo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(demo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(demo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(demo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new demo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `JSplitPane`. You can click on a button on the divider to have the divider go to the minimum or maximum value of the divider.

However, in order for the divider to go to the minimum the getMinimumSize() method must return a Dimension of (0, 0).

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Split Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean something like this

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TabSample {
  static void add(JTabbedPane tabbedPane, String text) {
    String text1 = "";
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    if (text.equals("tab1")){
     text1 = "";
    }
     else
    {
     text1 = text;


    }    


    JLabel label = new JLabel(text1);
    label.setFont(new Font(null,Font.BOLD,30));

    label.setText(text1);

    panel.add(label);
    tabbedPane.addTab(text,label);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tabbed Pane Sample");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.BOTTOM);
    String titles[] = { "tab1", "Jpanel Display 2"};
    for (int i = 0, n = titles.length; i < n; i++) {


      add(tabbedPane, titles[i]);
    }

    ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
      public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
        JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) changeEvent.getSource();
        int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println("Tab changed to: " + sourceTabbedPane.getTitleAt(index));
      }
    };
    tabbedPane.addChangeListener(changeListener);
    frame.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(400, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```